# How can I only slice the list when the function is not true in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, slice

I would like to slice my list when the function is not true, but I do not have an idea what I have to give back in the otherwise case. Do you have any idea ?

```
Example : 
sliceBy odd [1..5] == [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
sliceBy odd [1,3,2,4,5,7,4,6] == [[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[4,6]]
sliceBy even [1,3,2,4,5,7,4,6] == [[],[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[4,6]]
```

```
sliceBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
sliceBy _ []  = []
sliceBy _ [x] = [[x]]
sliceBy f (x:xs)
  | f x   = [x] : sliceBy f xs
  | otherwise = ??
```

Comment: This code adds an element to the beginning of the first list. It does not return the required output. ``(x:y):ys where y:ys = sliceBy f xs``

Comment: Hint: make use of [`span`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span) and [`break`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:break)

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [**`span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:span) and [**`break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:break) to get the longest prefixes where the list does/does not satisfy a given predicate. You thus can use this to make two functions `sliceBy` and `sliceByNot` that call each other:

```
sliceBy :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
sliceBy _ [] = []
sliceBy f xs = … : …
    where (xp, xnp) = span f xs

sliceByNot :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
sliceByNot _ [] = []
sliceByNot f xs = … : …
    where (xnp, xp) = break f xs
```

Where you need to fill in the `…` parts. The two functions thus should call each other.

Comment: With ViewPatterns: `sliceBy f (span f -> (yes, no)) = ..`